# Is there a way to update an existing array on a button click in Javascript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, function, button

So I have an issue (consisting of mainly Javascript). The basis of what I would like is a button in HTML which triggers a Javascript function to update an existing array with a specific scalar each time the button is pressed.

The code I have so far is this:

HTML Side: `<button type="button" onclick="scalar()">Click Me!</button>`

Javascript Side:

```
let data = [10, 20];

function scalar() {
    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++)
        data[i] *= 5;
    }

    alert(data);
}
```

What I expect this to do is when I press the button for the first time, it would update the array `data` to be `[50, 100]`. Next time I press it it updates `data` to `[250, 500]`. However, this does not work properly for some reason (I added the `alert(data)` to see what was in the array `data` on button press).

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I added a snippet with exactly the same code as you had, but it's showing syntax errors. You can [edit] your question, then click "edit this snippet" to edit the code and run it here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: What values are showing in the alert? Are these values always the same or do they change when you click on the buttons subsequent times? You say what your expected behaviour is but not what the actual behaviour is.

Comment: I have edited your snippet. It should work as per your expectation.

Comment: @MattStannett my apologies. It does not output anything whatsoever. The button does display, however when I click it, nothing is alerted (basically nothing seems to be happening when I click the button)

Comment: @santon I do not see your revision on my code snippet.

Comment: @Ali I have added snippet as an answer.

Comment: You're missing `}` in your script. Otherwise it works fine. Voting to close as off-topic due to a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet

```js
let data = [10, 20];

function scalar() {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] *= 5;
  }
  alert(data);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="scalar()">Click Me!</button>
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing an opening bracket after the start of the for loop. Code works as intended once you put that in.

```
let data = [10, 20];

function scalar() {
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] *= 5;
    }

    alert(data);
}
```